# How to fix site functionality caching?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, browser-cache

I'm using google cloud platform to serve a website. Whenever I update the website (create a build from the terminal and upload it to the Google bucket), users have been reporting site breakages until they hard refresh in browser or clear their caches manually.

Is there a way to configure the bucket to prevent this from happening?

Just to clarify, it's not images/files that are being cached, the whole site stops working when the bucket is updated until a user hard reloads the page in their browser

Comment: Your question does not have details on what is breaking your site. You can control how long objects are cached via cache headers. When modifying files such as JS and CSS, it is best to deploy new file names and not simply overwrite existing files. Given that a browser hard refresh solves the problem, you have a local file cache issue. Review the cache headers assigned to objects in storage. However, if the cache settings are one week, the browser will cache objects for up to one week. If you set the cache time to one minute, that will affect your site performance. I would use different names.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. To be fair, I don't really know what's breaking either since these are all user reports and I'm unable to replicate it, but more than one person has submitted this issue. I'll try your method. Thanks again.